# How to get the difference between two columns using Talend

Tags: talend

I Have two excel sheets that i want to compare using talend job

First excel named Compare_Me_1

| PN | STT | Designation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AY73101000 | 20 | RC0402FR-0743K2L |
| AY73101000 | 22 | RK73H1ETTP4322F |
| AY73101000 | 22 | ERJ-2RKF4322X |
| Ac2566 | 70 | CRCW040243K2FKED |

Second excel named Compare_Me_2

| PN | STT | Designation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AY73101000 | 20 | RC0402FR-0743K2L |
| AY73101000 | 22 | RK73H1ETTP4322F |
| AY73101000 | 21 | ERJ-2RKF4322X |
| Ac2566 | 70 | CRCW040243K2FKED |

what i want to achieve is this output

| PN1 | STT1 | STT2 | STT_OK_Ko | Designation1 | Designation2 | Designation_Ok_Ko |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AY73101000 | 20 | 20 | ok | RC0402FR-0743K2L | RC0402FR-0743K2L | ok |
| AY73101000 | 22 | 22 | ok | RK73H1ETTP4322F | RK73H1ETTP4322F | ok |
| AY73101000 | 22 | 21 | ko | ERJ-2RKF4322X | ERJ-2RKF4322X | ok |
| Ac2566 | 70 | 70 | ok | CRCW040243K2FKED | CRCW040243K2FKED | ok |

So to achieve this i developed a talend job that looks like below :

[image]

In My tMap i linked PN with a **leftouterjoin** and **All Matches** correspandance .

And to get for example STT_Ok_KO i used bellow code to compare my two input  :

```java
(!Relational.ISNULL(row14.STT) && !Relational.ISNULL(row13.STT) &&
 row14.STT.equals(row13.STT)  ) ||

(Relational.ISNULL(row14.STT) && Relational.ISNULL(row13.STT))
?"ok":"ko"
```

Is this the correct way to achieve my ouput ?  If not , recommand me to use an other method

Any suggest is welcome .

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to follow the long steps below :
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]